# How to get Request property in SOAP UI for REST service test

Tags: web-services, rest, soapui

I created a [simple project in SOAP UI](http://www.soapui.org/rest-testing/getting-started.html), and now am trying to extract some test suit properties using Setup Script. Only thing is, RawRequest and Request properties are empty, but I want to display them. Request does exist, but request and raw request properties are null. This is only case with REST services.

```
   def tcaseList = testSuite.getTestCaseList();
           // for each testCase
  def countTestCases = tcaseList.size();
  for(tc = 0;tc<countTestCases;tc++){
  def countTestSteps = tcaseList[tc].getTestStepList().size();
  for(i=0;i<countTestSteps;i++)
  {// get testStep
    def testStep = tcaseList[tc].getTestStepAt(i);
   runner = tcaseList[tc].run(new com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap(), false);
  def request = testStep.getPropertyValue("RawRequest");
  log.info(request.toString())
```

Any ideas why this property is null, and how to extract request and display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In REST Request on SOAPUI the `RawRequest` property is only available on REST Request which use POST which sends data not only parameters, in REST Request which use GET the `RawRequest` is empty. If you want instead to get the value of the GET parameters you can use this in your code:

```
 ...
 def paramValue = testStep.getPropertyValue("parameterName");
 ...
```

In REST Request which use POST and sends data you're already doing correctly with your code:

```
def request = testStep.getPropertyValue("RawRequest");
```

I add the follow images to illustrate what I'm explaining:

1. POST with not empty Request:

[image]

2. GET with empty Request:

[image]

**UPDATE**

So if you want to get all the parameters from your REST Requests you can add the follow groovy snippet to your code:

```
// your for loop...
for(i=0;i<countTestSteps;i++){// get testStep
    def testStep = tcaseList[tc].getTestStepAt(i)
    ...

    // code to get REST Request parameters and log to the console

    // to avoid errors if you've testSteps which doesn't are RestTestSteps (i.e groovy...)
    if(testStep instanceof com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.RestTestRequestStep){
        // ? is groovy operator to avoid NPE
        def parameters = testStep?.getTestRequest()?.getParams()
        // loop through the map parameters
        parameters.each { k,v ->
            // for each params print the name and the value
            log.info "$k : ${v.getValue()}"
        }
    }

    ...
```

If you need more info take a look at [`RestTestRequestStep` API](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/teststeps/RestTestRequestStep.html).

Hope this helps,

Comment: thanks @albiciff. but is there any way to display request? without property?

Comment: Hi @Vesna what did you mean with "any way to display request"? did you refer to log for example the parameters for the GET Request?

Comment: yes, exactly, I want to either to log it, or to take this string and put it in a file.

Comment: @Vesna I added a possible way to print in the log all the params and values from a REST Request, I thought that you can change it if prefers to save the result on a file `:)`. Hope it helps.

Comment: excellent! That was exactly what I was looking for. I created some kind of output, with the data I needed.